# Retreving Data from Mysql and sending it to sqlite

Tags: android

I am getting all the records from the mysql database through php and jason and  inserting those records in Sqlite.But everytime when that activity creates it is inserting duplicate entries in Sqlite.I want to check that if that value already exists in sqlite table then value should not be inserted in Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You should see if the record doesn't exist and then insert it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make entries of Sqlite databse unique.I was facing same problem But i have solved it.If you send me your code of sqlite where you are creating table.I will exactly tell you that will solve your problem